# Return promise from Koa controller action with error

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, koa

I'm trying to build REST api with Typescript, Koa and Sequelize.
It's quite simple and has only `app.ts` as an entrypoint, one controller and one model.

I got an error when I try to return a Promise (data from DB) from an action:

> "TypeError: Class constructor Book cannot be invoked without 'new'\n    at _loop_1 (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:124:47)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:178:17)\n    at _loop_1 (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:167:43)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:178:17)\n    at _loop_1 (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:167:43)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:178:17)\n    at _loop_1 (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:167:43)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:178:17)\n    at _loop_1 (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:167:43)\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/node_modules/class-transformer/TransformOperationExecutor.js:178:17)\n    at /production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:43:40\n    at Array.forEach ()\n    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/production/data/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:40:30)\n    at ClassTransformer.classToPlain (/production/data/src/ClassTransformer.ts:21:25)\n    at Object.classToPlain (/production/data/src/index.ts:17:29)\n    at KoaDriver.BaseDriver.transformResult (/production/data/src/driver/BaseDriver.ts:143:22)\n    at KoaDriver.handleSuccess (/production/data/src/driver/koa/KoaDriver.ts:222:23)\n    at /production/data/src/RoutingControllers.ts:161:45"
>   Blockquote

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2016",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon dist/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node"
  ],
  "author": "author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "koa": "^2.6.2",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "koa-multer": "^1.0.2",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "routing-controllers": "^0.7.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.4",
    "sequelize": "^4.39.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/koa": "^2.0.46",
    "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.0.32",
    "@types/koa-static": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.116",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.27.26",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Also I have nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/app.ts"
}
```

App.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createKoaServer} from "routing-controllers";
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';

const sequelize =  new Sequelize({
    host: '172.18.0.11',
    database: 'notes',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'root',
    modelPaths: [__dirname + '/models']
});

const port = 20000;
createKoaServer({
    controllers: [__dirname + "/controllers/*"]
}).listen(port);

console.log("Server running on port " + port);
```

In the directory `models` I have file `Book.ts`

```
import {Table, Column, Model, HasMany} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({tableName: 'Books'})
export class Book extends Model<Book> {

    @Column
    title: string;

    @Column
    author: string;
}
```

And finally in directory `controllers` I have file `BookController.ts`

```
import {Get, JsonController, Post, Patch, Param, State, Delete} from "routing-controllers";
import {Book} from "../models/Book";

@JsonController("/api")
export class BookController {
    @Get("/books")
    getAll() {
        return Book.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here, in the `BookController.ts` I try to return promise (as I read in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers#return-promises)) and got error. So, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in error message.
You have to create instance of Book class, using `new`

```
const book = new Book();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Get, JsonController, Post, Patch, Param, State, Delete} from "routing-controllers";
import {Book} from "../models/Book";

@JsonController("/api")
export class BookController {
    @Get("/books")
    getAll() {
        return new Book.findAll();
    }
}
```

Doesn't work with error:

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
>   src/controllers/BookController.ts(8,16): error TS2350: Only a void
>   function can be called with the 'new' keyword.